# Overheating and loud fan with ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Inspiron n5110

Tags: overheating

I'm a newbie with Ubuntu, my fan is so loud without doing anything on my laptop, So can anyone help to detect what are the reasons?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing xubuntu 14.04.4

That was fixed by switching to the intel driver (had the nouveau driver active which had been installed by default):

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Then you need to log out and back in, but I played safe and simply rebooted. After giving out a few puffs the thing is now as cool and quiet as before

Hope that helps